# How to perform transformation of CSV file using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, perl, csv, sed, awk

I was trying to solve one problem for a while now but without success. In start it looks like a trivial issue but I have stacked with it...

Anyhow, I need to solve following problem. I have very large CSV file with lines in following format:

```
NUMBER(9);NUMBER(1);NUMBER(9-10);NUMBER(2);NUMBER(1);...;NUMBER(2);NUMBER(1);STRING;DATE(DD.MM.YYYY);NUMBER(1351)
```

for example:

```
517755369;1;0001303717;48;1;63;8;50;2;51;6;53;7;55;3;57;4;59;5;;;;;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
```

In each line after first tree fields I have 1 to 10 pairs `NUMBER(2);NUMBER(1)`, followed by another three fields `STRING;DATE(DD.MM.YYYY);NUMBER(1351)`.

I need to transform that file in file with following structure:

```
517755369;1;0001303717;48;1;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
517755369;1;0001303717;63;8;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
517755369;1;0001303717;50;2;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
517755369;1;0001303717;51;6;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
517755369;1;0001303717;53;7;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
517755369;1;0001303717;55;3;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
517755369;1;0001303717;57;4;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
517755369;1;0001303717;59;5;CALL;07.12.2012;1351`
```

So each line from input file should be transformed to as many lines as original line has `NUMBER(2);NUMBER(1)` pairs.

Here is a sample of input file:

```
517760344;2;000601301061;31;1;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
518855369;1;000601303717;48;1;63;8;50;2;51;6;53;7;55;3;57;4;59;5;;;;;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
519775067;1;000601300771;4;2;6;3;19;1;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
617773407;1;000603252922;13;1;17;2;27;3;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
717764779;1;000601304021;31;1;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;CALL;07.12.2012;1351`
```

In general I need some *regexp* that I can use with **sed** or **awk** (or some **perl** script I can run against input file). The original input file has roughly 1–1.5M records. This task should be finished as quickly as possible (up to 5 minutes for transformation).

Thanks

Comment: A regex seems like the wrong tool for the job here.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to ask a question.

Comment: Question is How to do it?

Comment: Have you tried a CSV parser?

Comment: @nhahtdh, No I have not. This transformation is just one part of the job (the tricky part). Problem is that I 'm limited to tools that I have on my HP-UX box which is quite archaic :-)

Comment: The transformation is the easy part. Just parse the line into an array, splice the elements off start and end, then just loop over the remaining elements and print as needed.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065095/how-do-i-efficiently-parse-a-csv-file-in-perl

Comment: A good tool for the job is awk, using ';' as field separator (see the man page, look for FS). You don't really need regular expressions for splitting.

Comment: Split at ';', sort, print!

Comment: @naitoon, Could you pleas post any hint? I tried with awk (it was my first choice), but I failed. I Couldn't solve situations with variable number of NUMBER(2);NUMBER(1) pairs in different lines...

Comment: Don't use regular expressions.  Use the Text::CSV_XS module to take care of it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideas from @Kenosis, but different interpretation of specs:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @fields = split /;/;
    my $f = 3;
    while ($fields[$f]) {
      print join( ';', @fields[0 .. 2, $f, $f + 1, -3 .. -1]), "\n";
      $f += 2;
    }
}

__DATA__
517760344;2;000601301061;31;1;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
518855369;1;000601303717;48;1;63;8;50;2;51;6;53;7;55;3;57;4;59;5;;;;;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
519775067;1;000601300771;4;2;6;3;19;1;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
617773407;1;000603252922;13;1;17;2;27;3;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
717764779;1;000601304021;31;1;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
```

output:

```
perl 14528210.pl
517760344;2;000601301061;31;1;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
518855369;1;000601303717;48;1;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
518855369;1;000601303717;63;8;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
518855369;1;000601303717;50;2;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
518855369;1;000601303717;51;6;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
518855369;1;000601303717;53;7;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
518855369;1;000601303717;55;3;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
518855369;1;000601303717;57;4;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
518855369;1;000601303717;59;5;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
519775067;1;000601300771;4;2;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
519775067;1;000601300771;6;3;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
519775067;1;000601300771;19;1;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
617773407;1;000603252922;13;1;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
617773407;1;000603252922;17;2;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
617773407;1;000603252922;27;3;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
717764779;1;000601304021;31;1;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
```

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I need...and it is super fast :-) Thanks once again.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    print +( join ';', ( split /;/ )[ 0 .. 4, -3 .. -1 ] ) . "\n";

}
```

Output on your data:

```
517760344;2;000601301061;31;1;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
518855369;1;000601303717;48;1;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
519775067;1;000601300771;4;2;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
617773407;1;000603252922;13;1;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
717764779;1;000601304021;31;1;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
```

Usage: `perl file.csv >out.csv`.

It appears that you want the first five fields and the last three.  The above `split`s on `;`, re`join`s with `;` and then prints the modified record.

Comment: I want the first tree fields and any pair of numbers which follows in separate line. for example 518855369;1;000601303717;48;1;CALL;07.12.2012;1351 and 518855369;1;000601303717;63;8;CALL;07.12.2012;1351 and so on...

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^(([^;]*;){3})(([0-9]+;){2})(([0-9]*;)*)(([^;]*;?){3})$/\1\3\7\n\1\5\7/;Ta;P;:a;D' file
```

- `s/^(([^;]*;){3})(([0-9]+;){2})(([0-9]*;)*)(([^;]*;?){3})$/\1\3\7\n\1\5\7/` this substitution command constructs two strings. The first is the intended string followed by a newline, the second is the original string less the first pair of numbers. So `^(([^;]*;){3})` represents the first three fields, `(([0-9]+;){2})` the first pair of numbers,`(([0-9]*;)*)` the remaining pairs of numbers and `(([^;]*;?){3})$` the last three fields.
- `Ta` if the substitution command fails jump to label `a`
- `P` print upto the first newline in the pattern space.
- `:a` label `a`
- `D` delete upto and including the first newline and begin the next cycle. Do not read in another line until the pattern space is empty.

So, in essence, the `s/.../.../` and the `D` commands are used to invoke a loop which prints a constructed string until the substitution command fails which then ends the loop. The remaining string is deleted completely and the next line is begun.

Comment: Great job, this is excellent solution. I will appreciate if you could explain me this regex. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution in one-liner form, using the [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV) module.

```
perl -MText::CSV -lwe '$c = Text::CSV->new({
    sep_char=>';',
    eol=>$/
});                  
while($r = $c->getline(*STDIN)) { 
    my @a = splice @$r,0,3;            # remove 3 first elements
    my @c = splice @$r,-3;             # remove 3 last elements
    @$r = grep $_ ne '', @$r;          # remove empty elements
    while(@$r) {                       # while array is not empty
        $c->print(*STDOUT, [@a, splice(@$r,0,2),@c]);    # print all elements
    } }"
```

**Output:**

```
517755369;1;0001303717;48;1;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
517755369;1;0001303717;63;8;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
517755369;1;0001303717;50;2;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
517755369;1;0001303717;51;6;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
517755369;1;0001303717;53;7;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
517755369;1;0001303717;55;3;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
517755369;1;0001303717;57;4;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
517755369;1;0001303717;59;5;CALL;07.12.2012;1351
```

So basically, like I said in my comment, remove first 3 elements and 3 last elements and store in separate arrays. Remove empty elements. Loop around the remaining elements and print as necessary.

Comment: This is nice piece of code. I already find similar solution (using Text::CSV modul) online but I'm not sure if Text::CSV module is available on our HP-UX box which has, as I mentioned above, quite archaic setup. I will test this also when back to work on Monday and let you know. On my Ubuntu box at home it works fine.