# perl splitting function exception conditions

Tags: regex, perl

I have a requirement for splitting in perl. Please have a look in the below example:

```
"john","David2,mick",25,"12-12-2009","male"
```

I have to split this record on each comma (,) that isn't inside quotes.

Expected output is:

```
john 
david2mick 
25 
12-12-2009
male
```

Could you please help me with this.

Comment: Don't use regexes, use a CSV parser like [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/module/Text::CSV). This handles embedded commas correctly.

Comment: `"David2,mick"` instead of `David2,mick"`?

Comment: Your example shows removing quote pairs, removing commas which are inside quote pairs, and then splitting on commas.  But that's not exactly what you asked.  Please clarify.

Comment: This is an epic fail. Your sample code and expected output do not match on your most important aspect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3065232/223226

Comment: Hi Rohit,  Iam not able to install these modules in  unix box since I dont have privilages.

Comment: This is a CSV file, but I dont have permissions to execute native perl modules... So iam trying with out CSV module

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I efficiently parse a CSV file in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065095/how-do-i-efficiently-parse-a-csv-file-in-perl)

Comment: If you wanted to use a regular expression you could do: ("[^"]*"|[^,]*)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Text::ParseWords`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aParseWords), a core module in Perl 5. It is a light weight option to `Text::CSV`, assuming this is not proper csv data you have here.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Text::ParseWords;

my $str = qq("john","David2,mick",25,"12-12-2009","male");
my @list = quotewords(',', 0, $str);

print Dumper \@list;
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          'john',
          'David2,mick',
          '25',
          '12-12-2009',
          'male'
        ];
```

Comment: After the split, it's then possible to iterate through the list to remove the commas: `s/,//g for @list;`

Comment: @PlatinumAzure: `tr/,//d for @list`

Comment: Friends, Thanks for all the help. I am able to achive my Output.

Comment: @David If you feel happy with the answers, you can accept one of them by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

This is a CSV file. It's best to use the Text::CSV module

```
use Text::CSV;
my $line = '"john","David2,mick",25,"12-12-2009","male"';
my $csv = Text::CSV->new();
$csv->parse($line);
my @columns = $csv->fields();
```