# perl split a string on ","

Tags: regex, perl, split

I am trying to split several hundred lines read from a CSV file on `,`.  E.g.:

```
"Acme services","Sesame street","zip","0,56","2013-10-21"  
"Black adder, intra-national Association","shaftsville rd","zap code","0,50","2014-10-14"
```

etc.

I could split the first row on `,`, but this would not work for the second row.  However, if I split on `,` then I would trap these cases.  I could then remove the " using simple regex (e.g. `$col[i] =~ s/\"+//g`)

I have tried `@cols = split(/\",\"/,$line)`, and I've tried `split('","',$lines)` and various variations, but every time, I get the full `$line` in `$col[0]`, with `$cols[1:n]` as empty.

Any help would be much appreciated!  Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using a parser?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065095/how-do-i-efficiently-parse-a-csv-file-in-perl

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not use [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV). This will take care of edge cases where you have commas in values and all sorts of other problems,

from the cpan page

```
use Text::CSV;

my @rows;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1 } )  # should set binary attribute.
                or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();

open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", "test.csv" or die "test.csv: $!";
while ( my $row = $csv->getline( $fh ) ) {
    $row->[2] =~ m/pattern/ or next; # 3rd field should match
    push @rows, $row;
}
$csv->eof or $csv->error_diag();
close $fh;

$csv->eol ("\r\n");

open $fh, ">:encoding(utf8)", "new.csv" or die "new.csv: $!";
$csv->print ($fh, $_) for @rows;
close $fh or die "new.csv: $!";
```

---

EDIT worked example assuming two given lines are in a.txt

```
use strict;
use Text::CSV;

my @rows;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1 } )  # should set binary attribute.
                or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();

open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", "a.txt" or die "a.txt: $!";
while ( my $row = $csv->getline( $fh ) ) {

    foreach(@$row){
        print "$_\n";
    }
    print "\n";
}
$csv->eof or $csv->error_diag();
close $fh;
```

gives

```
Acme services
Sesame street
zip
0,56
2013-10-21

Black adder, intra-national Association
shaftsville rd
zap code
0,50
2014-10-14
```

Comment: `split /,/` is appropriate unless your data fields are quoted, as here. But the module is preferable for anything more complex. Note that `Text::CSV` will use `Text::CSV_XS` (the faster, C-based module) if it is installed. Otherwise it will use the similar pure-Perl version `Text::CSV_PP`. For most purposes either one is fine.

Comment: @ KeepCalmAndCarryOn Thanks.  I have implemented Text::CSV successfully in my code.  However, it is simply splitting on ',' as before.  I have tried changing sep to "," i.e. my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({ binary => 1, sep_char => "\",\"" }); but have been unsuccessful in implementing this.  Could you possibly spoon-feed me on how to do this? I didn't find the documentation terribly clear, perhaps because my Perl is fairly primitive.  Thanks!

Comment: updated answer. What exactly are you looking to do?

Comment: Thanks, I've got it working using your foreach(@$row){.  I had been having difficulty with using $row->[i], although its possible that the bug was elsewhere in my code.