# Perl: How can I split a string on an unquoted instance of a character

Tags: perl, split

In perl, how can I split a string along only unquoted delimiters?  i.e. the following string:

```
my $line = '"a quoted, comma", word1, word2';
```

should result in an array with the elements:

```
"a quoted, comma"
 word1
 word2
```

Comment: Related: [How do I efficiently parse a CSV file in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065095/how-do-i-efficiently-parse-a-csv-file-in-perl)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `parse_line()` of [Text::ParseWords](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/ParseWords.html).

```
use  Text::ParseWords;

my $line = '"a quoted, comma", word1, word2';

my @parsed = parse_line(',', 1, $line);

# print "@parsed\n"; # this will print in single line

# To print in new line
foreach (@parsed)
{
    print "$_\n";
}
```

Output:

```
"a quoted, comma"
 word1
 word2
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Is there someway I can tell ParseWords to treat both ""'s and matched parentheses as quotes?  E.g.  (a,b) is a word?

Comment: Dear downvoter, your comment will help me to improve my answer. Do not forget to tell us why did you downvote? :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a simple alternate regex pattern

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $line = q<"a quoted, comma", word1, word2>;

my @words = $line =~ / (?: "[^"]*" | [^,] )+ /xg;

say for @words;
```

#### output

```
"a quoted, comma"
 word1
 word2
```