# Split into words by an uncommented comma that is not inside matching parentheses

Tags: regex, perl

Consider the following string:

```
blah, foo(a,b), bar(c,d), yo
```

I want to extract a list of strings:

```
blah
foo(a,b)
bar(c,d)
yo
```

It seems to me that I should be able to use quote words here, but I'm struggling with the regex. Can someone help me out?

Comment: I added a solution that handles nested parentheses. It's probably slower than @stribizhev's, though, so if you don't need to handle that, use theirs.

Comment: Also, wild guess, but for the string you wrote, you can simply split on `, ` (note the space). The inner "arguments" don't contain spaces. If your input is like that too, you might as well just do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl has a little thing [regex recursion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html), so you might be able to look for:

- either a bare word like `blah` containing no parentheses (`\w+`)
- a "call", like `\w+\((?R)(, *(?R))*\)`

The total regex is `(\w+(\((?R)(, ?(?R))*\))?)`, which [seems to work](https://regex101.com/r/lQ6zD8/3).

Comment: A better and cleaner way i would say

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex to use in split:

```
\([^()]*\)(*SKIP)(*F)|\s*,\s*
```

With `\([^()]*\)`, we match a `(` followed with 0 or more characters other than `(` or `)` and then followed with `)`. We fail the match with `(*SKIP)(*F)` if that parenthetical construction is found, and then we only match the comma surrounded with optional whitespaces.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lQ6zD8/2)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $string= "blah, foo(a,b), bar(c,d), yo";
my @string = split /\([^()]*\)(*SKIP)(*F)|\s*,\s*/, $string;

foreach(@string) {
    print "$_\n";
}
```

To account for commas inside nested balanced parentheses, you can use

```
my @string = split /\((?>[^()]|(?R))*\)(*SKIP)(*F)|\s*,\s*/, $string;
```

Here is an [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/JwKp0Q)

With `\((?>[^()]|(?R))*\)` we match all balanced `()`s and fail the match if found with the verbs `(*SKIP)(*F)`, and then we match a comma with optional whitespace around (so as not to manually trim the strings later).

For a `blah, foo(b, (a,b)), bar(c,d), yo` string, the result is:

```
blah
foo(b, (a,b))
bar(c,d)
yo
```

Comment: This doesn't handle `blah, foo(a, bar(b, c)), yo`, but I'm not sure if the OP needs it to.

Comment: @Mauris: That is easy to fix as you see.

Comment: @stribizhev your fix hasnt made any change it seems https://regex101.com/r/hR7tH4/8

Comment: @vks: PCRE and Perl are different a bit, it works in Perl.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31183116/4248931) given by *Borodin* for one of your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31181981/4248931) (which is similar to this question). A small change of regex will give you desire output: (this will not work for nested parentheses)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my $line = q<blah, foo(a,b), bar(c,d), yo>;

my @words = $line =~ / (?: \([^)]*\) | [^,] )+ /xg;

say for @words;
```

Output:

```
blah
 foo(a,b)
 bar(c,d)
 yo
```